# Select list preenchido dinamicamente opção selecionada com AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, selecteditem, selected-option

Preciso trazer um `select option` com a opção selecionada sendo preenchido dinamicamente.

Tenho em meu controller o preenchimento da lista assim:

```
$scope.$watch('IdCategoria', function() {
            $http.get("/api/Categoria/GetList", {  }).success(function(response) {
                $scope.categorias = response;
            });
        });
```

E o meu `select` está assim:

```
<select ng-model="newCtrl.IdCategoria" required class="form-control" data-live-search="true" ng-options="c.Value as c.Text for c in categorias">
<option value="">Selecione uma categoria</option>
</select>
```

Onde o `newCtrl.IdCategoria` é o campo com o `Id` da categoria selecionada, no qual o `select` deveria vir selecionado.

Eu li aqui no *Stack* que usando o `track by` deveria funcionar, porem se eu setar `track by newCtrl.IdCategoria`, tanto na edição quanto no cadastro eu não consigo realizar a seleção de outra opção.

Já tentei também o uso do `ng-init`, mas também sem sucesso:

`ng-init="newCtrl.IdCategoria= newCtrl.categorias[newCtrl.IdCategoria]"`

Lembrando que minhas categorias são:

```
[{"Value":"24","Text":"Categoria 1"},{"Value":"25","Text":"Categoria 2"}]
```

**EDIT1** já testei assim

```
<select ng-model="newCtrl.IdCategoria" required class="form-control" data-live-search="true">
<option value="">Selecione uma categoria</option>
<option ng-repeat="c in categorias" value="{{c.Value}}">{{c.Text}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Já deu uma olhada na [documentação](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)?

Comment: Já sim... não sei se é por causa das informações dinamicas mas não funciona de jeito nenhum.. inclusive já testei usando ng-repeat no options e nada!

Answer (score 1):

Dentro do seu controller:

```
$scope.$watch('IdCategoria', function() {
            $http.get("/api/Categoria/GetList", {  })
            .success(function(response) {
                if (response.length > 0) {
                     response.unshift({"Value":"0", "Text":"Selecione uma categoria"});
                   $scope.categorias = {
                                         availableOptions: response,
                                         selectedOption: {
                                             Value: response[0].Value,
                                             Text: response[0].Text
                                        }
                                    };
               }
            });
        });
```

Depois na view:

```
<div ng-controller="newCtrl as ctrl">

   <select name="selecao" class="form-control" id="selecao" required class="form-control" data-live-search="true"
      ng-options="option.Text for option in ctrl.categorias.availableOptions track by option.Value"
      ng-model="ctrl.categorias.selectedOption"></select>
```

Lembrando que isso só vai rolar se houver uma interação neste elemento  "IdCategoria" que eu não faço ideia do que seja e de onde você está interagindo ele, pois a função $watch é para escutar o elemento, quando ele for alterado:

Veja um exemplo:

```
angular
  .module('seuApp', [])
  .controller('ACtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.collection = [];
  })
  .controller('BCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('nome.input', function (newValue, oldValue) {
         console.log('escutando elemento, valos novo: ' + newValue);
    });
  });
```

E na HTML:

```
  <html ng-app="seuApp">
      <body ng-controller="ACtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="(key, nome) in collection" ng-controller="BCtrl">
          Nome {{key}}: <input ng-model="nome.input" ng-change="doSomething()">
          <br />
         Olá seu nome é {{ nome.input }}
        </div>
        <button ng-click="collection.push([])">Incluir nome</button>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Olha o [**JSFIDDLE (1)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/tchqktvk/) e [**JSFIDDLE (2)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/tchqktvk/1/)

Comment: Bom dia Ivan, então.. não deu certo, pelo seguinte motivo. na linha onde você define o seletedOption[0] indicando que o selecionado é o indice 0 da lista, dai ele trás o primeiro item selecionado ao invés de selecionar o item que veio da base no qual eu informo aqui em meu ng-model='newCtrl.IdCategoria'

Answer (score 0):

Ivan,

Seu json está vindo o value como um string, verifique se seu IdCategoria é uma string ou um integer, se forem de tipos incompatíveis você terá que ou mudar o seu serviço e trazer os valores dos mesmos tipos, ou mudar na interface, usando um toString ou parseInt, a forma mais correta é mudar o serviço, depois que fizer isso a segunda opção que você tentou value="{{c.Value}}" deverá funcionar.

Vale a pena dar uma olhada também aqui:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso

```
<select ng-model="newCtrl.IdCategoria" required class="form-control" data-live-search="true" ng-options="c.Value as c.Text for c in categorias">
<option value="">{{newCtrl.IdCategoria ? newCtrl.IdCategoria : "Selecione uma categoria"}}</option>
</select>
```

pode dar certo caso o *newCtrl.IdCategoria* não esteja vazio se vier vazio aparece *Selecione uma categoria*